# Installing the same python environment on another machine

Tags: python, linux

I'm developing a python project on my desktop (OS X) and it's running well. Now I need to run it on a computing cluster that is running Linux and I have no root access. On my Home in the computing cluster I installed Anaconda locally. Then when I run my project there I got so many strange bugs and errors. THe code runs fine on my desktop. So I thought probably the problem is that probably Anaconda has newr modules than what I have and that's probably causing errors. (backward compatibility issues)

Is there any way to use the same python modules versions I have in my desktop on the computing cluster?

I wonder if there is a command that produces all the packages and modules I have on my desktop with their versions and then import this file into some tool in that linux machine and then I get a cloned version of my setup. Is there something like that?

Comment: I think you should deal with new errors one by one. Re-installing Python packages is not so hard. :)

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but pyinstaller looks at all the dependencies of an application and creates an installer that gets them for the new user.

Comment: Did you change your files of python code in your Mac into Linux file style?  Text files in Mac use CR("\r") as line separator, and text files in Unix/Linux use LF("\n") as line separator. You need to convert CR to LF when you transfer files from Mac to Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 4):

### Use pyenv to control the python version

[pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) is designed for installing python into the home folder so you don't need root access (but even with root access it's a great idea), it lets you use a specified version of python within your home folder hierarchy rather than the OS version. You should also install [pyenv virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) so you can use a virtual environment for your project (not strictly essential, but virtual environments are a great idea and you should always use one, with pyenv they're practically effortless).

One of the neat things about pyenv is the `pyenv local` command which specifies which version of python (or which virtualenv) should be used for a folder (and subfolders), once you've used `pyenv local` in your project folder to set the python version any time you use the `python` command it'll use the version set by `pyenv local`. It's not needed if you only install one version of python, and don't use a virtualenv (in that case you can use `pyenv global` to set the version for the user). The neatest thing about pyenv local/global setup is it works great with both scripts and manually invoking python, it is simply set-and-forget unlike other python environment managers which require activation.

In brief, once you've set up pyenv you control exactly what version of python will run, and as it is installed into the home folder the OS has no power to affect it.

Having installed pyenv and pyenv virtualenv, you would then use it to install the same version of python as is used on your development machine, the commands you'd run would be something like this:

```
pyenv install 3.4.2
pyenv virtualenv 3.4.2 my_project_env
cd my_project
pyenv local my_project_env
```

### Install modules into python environment

To get a list of python module version use `pip freeze`, you can do this on your development machine:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now copy `requirements.txt` to your deployment machines (with pyenv already setup using `pyenv local` or `pyenv global`) and run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which will install the same modules into the python environment.

### Duplicating a pyenv

While it's kind of dodgy, once you've done this, you can even copy the entire installation (i.e. at least the `.bashrc` file and `.pyenv` folder) onto other machines, and if the machines have the same OS and the home folders have the same name, the transplanted environment should work fine. It might be more responsible to use a setup script but I have copied pyenv environments without anything terrible happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed you could try this [pip freeze](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html).

If you want to get list of modules from python shell:

```
help('modules')
```