# Numpy's asarray() doesn't work with csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a big trouble. I wrote code in python that is using `Numpy` and `Networkx` 6 months ago with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

#add node and edges to G ...

A = nx.adj_matrix(Gx)
A = np.asarray(A)
```

Now I need to run this on a computing cluster with the latest version of Numpy. But when I run this code it fails, because `A = np.asarray(A)` returns `()`

I have no idea what to do, since this code is everywhere. Is this a bug in Numpy or what?

This question is related to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273200/installing-the-same-python-environment-on-another-machine)

Comment: it works for me... NumPy 1.9.0, Python 2.7 64 bit, NetWorkX 1.8.1

Comment: it is not `csr_matrix` in my case, but `np.matrix`... if you have a version which `G` is a `csr_matrix`, just do `G.toarray()`

Comment: it fails with `csr_matrix`

Comment: Well, np.asarray(A) returns a dtype=object array with shape=() for Numpy/Scipy 1.6.2/0.14.0 and 1.8.2/0.13.3 and 1.9.0/0.14.0. In particular, I don't find it returns (). For what version combinations do you obtain a different behavior?

Comment: What did `nx.adj_matrix(Gx)` return originally?  A sparse matrix, or matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The function **`nx.adj_matrix(G)`** returns a `scipy.sparse` matrix object containing the adjacency matrix of G.

If you want a `numpy` matrix or array you can do that simply with a **`.todense()`** method:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.path_graph(4)

In [3]: S = nx.adj_matrix(G)

In [4]: S
Out[4]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [5]: A = S.todense()

In [6]: A
Out[6]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [7]: A.A
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: yeah but that modification to numpy made my entire code un-usable now :( it's horror I can't believe it! I have bugs all over my code because of this backward compatibility issue!

Comment: You could simply replace nx.adj_matrix with your own very small function that returns nx.adj_matrix(G).todense() as shown above.  Not that horrible :-)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this pull request:

https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/67bf6c1b4d2844a859b21057a63a72b36a45906b

In Nov 2013, `networkx` changed `adjacency_matrix` (syn for `adj_matrix`) from producing a dense matrix to producing a sparse one.  In a number of cases they had to add `.todense()` when calling this function.

So the change may have been in `networkx` rather than `numpy`.  I don't think `np.asarray` has ever been `sparse` aware.  Usually it is used to convert a `np.matrix` to `np.ndarray`.

---

Using `adj_matrix().A` should work in both environments.  Both `np.matrix` and `csr_matrix` have this property.